# mutt mark as read and archive

Tags: mutt

I am using this macro to mark an email as read and archive it:

```
macro index,pager a ":set confirmappend=no
delete=yes\n<clear-flag>N<tag-prefix><save-message>=Archives\n<sync-mailbox>:set
confirmappend=yes delete=yes\n<next-undeleted>"
```

The macro works but only in the index. It does not work in pager despite the "pager" mention.

How can I have this macro work also in pager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is just that going to the pager remove the N flag of the email. So, of course, the macro doesn't work anymore...

Answer (score 0):

You may have a `macro pager a "whatever"` defined after your mentioned macro. Please open the pager and press `?`. Then have a look what `a` is doing.